# Ruby on Rails Class method scoped objects references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, metaprogramming, class-method

I was wondering If I could modify objects using a class method.

For example, `users = User.scoped` # This will select all the objects

And, suppose, I want to assign a variable for each of the object there is. Let's say, I want them to share a single value. So, when I try to access, for example, `users.first.my_variable` it would produce the value, I want.

My naive implementation:

```
def self.set_my_variable(variable_value) 
    scoped.tap do |obj|
       obj.my_variable = variable_value
    end   
end
```

So, ideally, when I wan't this variable to be set, I should call the class method like this: `users.set_my_variable("hello, stackoverflow")`

But, when I try accessing the variable through arbitrary object of the set, like this:

> users.first.my_variable

I get **nil**. Comparing .object_id's in both: `obj.object_id` and `users.first.object_id` shows that they are different. Why so ? I thought that they share the same reference (pointing to the same objects)

Any way of fixing it (preferrably without passing a collection to this class method) ?

Comment: Just for clarification - you use Rails 3.2, right?

Comment: Yes. I use Rails 3.2.12

Answer (score 0):

you need to save object to database:

```
   obj.my_variable = variable_value
   obj.save
```

Comment: Even when I update "virtual" attributes (variables) ? This is weird. Isn't there anything simplier ?

I should have clearly stated that "my_variable" is VIRTUAL. It is used for internal purposes.